# Is there any efficient way to select all from one table and insert in another

Tags: php, pdo

I need  help with PHP PDO and SQLITE3. I have table device like

```
CREATE TABLE device (
 object_identifier integer PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
 object_name varchar(1024),
 vendor_name varchar(1024),
 vendor_identifier integer,
 model_name varchar(1024),
 firmware_revision varchar(1024),
 application_software_version varchar(1024),
 protocol_version integer,
 protocol_revision integer,
 max_apdu_length_accepted integer,
 apdu_timeout integer,
 number_of_apdu_retries integer,
 database_revision integer,
 system_status integer,
 protocol_object_types_supported varchar(65),
 segmentation_supported integer,
 protocol_services_supported varchar(65),
 local_time varchar(32),
 local_date varchar(32),
 location varchar(1024),
 object_list_num integer
);
```

and I have another table  fan_coil_jebeni like

```
CREATE TABLE fan_coil_jebeni (
 object_identifier integer PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
 object_name varchar(1024),
 vendor_name varchar(1024),
);
```

My question is there any efficient way to select all from device and insert into fan_coil_jebeni without iterative comming through cursor ( there is a bunch of rows to beinserted ) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this:

```
INSERT INTO fan_coil_jebeni SELECT object_identifier, object_name, vendor_name FROM device;
```

Answer (score 4):

you can use [insert ... select](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-select.html)

```
insert into fan_coil_jebeni(a,b,c) select a,b,c from device
```

Comment: That doesn't take into account if this is run multiple times. The primary key on `fan_coil_jebeni` will fail due to duplicate entry.

Comment: This does not work if e.g. column `a` is an unique auto-increment in both tables (cause you can't insert column a, but all others/remaining). Also if `a` is used as ID, it should stay the same in both tables, so a bad workaround like removing the auto-increment temporarly does not work also.

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `table1` SELECT * FROM `table2`
```